# How to check rationality, irrationality and algebraicity in this case?

Tags: functions, logarithms, irrational-numbers

This question was asked in a test and the use of calculator was not allowed.

> Choose the correct one:
>
> (A) $\log_e x$ can be defined as a real-valued function of $x$ for all $x\in R$
>
> (B) $\log_{10}5$ is a rational number
>
> (C) $\log_{10}5$ is an irrational number
>
> (D) $\log_e x$ is algebraic number

I know that (A) cannot be the answer because $\log_e x$ is not defined for negative values of $x$

How do I check the validity of the other options without using a calculator. Please help.

Comment: How would a calculator help?   Hint:  if $\log_{10} 5 =\frac ab$ then $5^b=2^a\times 5^a$,

Comment: (D) What is $x$? A negative number?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, It is not specified in the option. I think $x$ belongs to the general domain of the logarithmic function.

Comment: @lulu, You could check the whether the digits repeat after a certain number of digits using a calculator.

Comment: Well...that wouldn't prove anything.  An apparent pattern might not persist and the absence of a pattern might only mean that the period is bigger than the output of your calculator.

Comment: For instance, in this case we have $\log_{10}5=0.6989700043360188047\cdots$. That certainly looks irrational but how do you know that it doesn't eventually become periodic?  Numerical methods really don't help with questions like these.

Comment: @lulu, I have read somewhere that the digits repeat atmost after 7 places after the decimal.

Comment: Sorry? That is clearly not true.  The rational number $\frac {123456789}{10^9}=.123456789$ does not start repeating until after the the $9^{th}$ place (and there is nothing special about $9$).

Comment: The wording of (A) leaves much to be desired, and I certainly wouldn't want to be in the position of defending this problem from having a unique answer choice (which is strongly implied by the use of "**the** correct one"). Also, there is a missing quantifier in (D), or else '$x$' was written by mistake. (Does it mean "for some $x$" or does it mean "for all $x$"? Or perhaps something else?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume by contrary that $\log_{10}5\in \Bbb Q$ then we have$$\log_{10}5={p\over q}\quad,\quad \gcd(p,q)=1$$with $0<p<q$ since $1<5<10$, therefore$$5=10^{p\over q}\implies 5^q=10^p\implies 5^{q-p}=2^p$$which is impossible since **no power of $2$ can be any power on $5$ except $1=2^0=5^0$**. Finally we conclude that $\log_{10}5\notin \Bbb Q$ and **(C) is correct.**

Also (D) is wrong. Let $x=e^\pi$ and note that $\pi$ is transcendental.

Comment: I could not understand the last line of your answer.

Comment: I mean $\pi=\log_e e^\pi$ is not algebraic.